# Running a gas line to the garage

Tags: garage, natural-gas, septic

Hey guys I need to run a buried gas line from my house to the garage. Its about 60 ft run. It passes through my driveway (gravel). How deep am I supposed to burry it to be safe? What line should I buy? Also I have a septic system (recently moved) that I am not totally sure where it even is. I am worried about hitting the tile or the system while trenching. How can I be sure I can trench without running into something.

Thanks,
Kevin
Leamington, ON
Canada

Comment: I don't think you can add/alter the gas supply line without notifying the gas supplier (your gas company). You shall at least consult with a licensed plumber in your local area.

Comment: Starting point is "Miss Utility" or similar utility service locator. Free in most areas, required by law in many areas. That will get electric, gas, water/sewer, cable, etc. utility companies to mark all the stuff they know about. In many areas if you dig and damage utility lines/pipes and you didn't get them marked first then you are in *big* trouble. That should just leave your septic system to figure out.